# Font "Sabon" into TeXworks

Tags: fonts, texworks

What has to be done to include a new font such as Sabon into TeXworks? I already have the necessary files, however, ´cause I´m a beginner with LaTex, I can´t manage to bring the files into TeXworks. Somebody able and interested to help me?

Comment: Your question is a kind of category error: TeXWorks is a front end to a TeX Distribution, so there is no coherent way to "bring the files into TeXWorks" (since I'm assuming that you don't simply want to type your source files in Sabon within TeXWorks.) Are you asking about how to create LaTeX documents using the Sabon font?

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming what Alan says in his note is right, and that you want to create documents using Sabon, not somehow use Sabon in TeXworks' GUI.

The easiest way then, is probably to use XeLaTeX. First, makse sure Sabon is installed and is accessible to other programs. Add the following to your LaTeX preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Sabon} % Or it might need to be \setmainfont{Sabon LT Std} or something
```

To build your document, choose "XeLaTeX" from TeXworks's dropdown box.

Now, Sabon should be the main font of the document. For more information, see the [fontspec](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package documentation.